# PostgreSQL: how can I identify rows in a child table?

Tags: postgresql

First of all, excuse me for being a database design newbie.

Suppose I have the table `books` defined as:

```
id: integer (autoincremented)
title: string
```

I want to create a table with comments about books. I've come up with two possible ways to define the `comments` table:

### OPTION 1

```
id: BIG integer (autoincremented) #Here I use BIGINT because 32 bits are not enough to handle all possible comments for all books
book: integer (foreign key to books.id)
text: string 

PRIMARY KEY: id
```

### OPTION 2

```
book: integer (foreign key to books.id)
index: integer (incremented by the 'before create' trigger on table `comments`)
text: string

PRIMARY KEY: (book, index)
```

I find **OPTION 1** the simplest one because the primary key is just a number. The drawback is that I need a 64 bit integer and this may be an issue for 32 bit PHP platforms or even in Rails (in which changing the default type of the `id` column automatically added by ActiveRecord is a little bit tricky).

On the other hand, **OPTION 2** requires an annoying two-integer primary key that has to be maintained by a trigger function. However it uses friendly 32 bit integers and logically fits better in the nested structure of the tables (comment 2 of book 123 rather than comment 2222 book 123 in the case of option 1).

Which of both options is the best one? Are both equally fine? Is there another better way to achieve the same purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: What about PK for comments as a combination of comment_id (integer) and book_id, without the trigger? CREATE TABLE book_comment (id serial, book_id int references book(id), comment text  , constraint myck primary key (id , book_id)); There is no need to use a trigger. "Serial" takes care of that.

Comment: @Jayadevan, AFAIK "serial" does not increment per-partition basis. This means that comment.id would overflow if we assume it is an integer, not a big integer. Notice that if we had 4 milion books, and 1000 comments per book (consider these values plausible in other applications, not in a library), then we would need a 64 bit id.

Answer (score 0):

Propably a matter of opinion but I would definitely go for option 1 as it is easier, cleaner and a better offset should you at some point wish to be able to assign something to the comments - like e.g. votes. In such a scenario option 2 would require composite foreign key on the votes table - not wrong but not pretty either.

Answer (score 0):

You could use timestamp instead of integer in Your example 2.
The order of composite key members depends on the business logics of Your app, if the book matters, then it is the first member of index.